# Send HTML Mail from Cocoa with Mail.app

Tags: objective-c, applescript, scripting-bridge

I'm trying to send html email from Cocoa app, through Mail.app. I want to open new message in Mail.app, include subject, recipient and add HTML Body with links and other content. But can't find the way to do this.
I already tried Scripting Bridge, but MailOutgoingMessage class doesn't have content type i can add content in plaintext.

tried AppleScript, something like this:

```
set htmlContent to read "/Path/index.html"
set recipientList to {"mail@mail.com"}

tell application "Mail"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"qwerty", visible:true}
    tell newMessage
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:"mail@s.com"}
            set html content to htmlContent
        --send
    end tell
end tell
```

this code send email with html, only if I'm changing --send to send. But i need to send letter later, after user made some changes.

Answer (score 7):

To **recap the problem**: Using AppleScript to create a message with HTML content for *interactive* editing *does not work* (as of OS X 10.9.2): the new-message form comes up with an *empty* body.

This should be considered a **bug** and I encourage everyone to let Apple know at http://bugreport.apple.com - *caveat*: the `html content` `message` class property is *not* defined in `Mail.sdef`, `Mail.app`'s AppleScript dictionary, so assigning HTML may not be officially supported.

There is a **workaround**, but it ain't pretty:

- Create the message *invisibly*.
- Save it *as a draft*.
- Open the *draft* message, at which point the HTML content *will* appear.

Implementing this robustly is challenging, because several workarounds are required. The following code tries its hardest, though:

Note: Since the code uses GUI scripting, **Access for Assistive Devices must be enabled** (via `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Accessibility`) for the application running this code (e.g., `AppleScript Editor` or, if run via `osascript`, `Terminal.app`).

```applescript
# Example values; use `read someFile` to read HTML from a file.
set htmlContent to "<html><body><h1>Hello,</h1><p>world.</p></body></html>"
set recipientList to {"person1@example.com", "person2@example.com"}
set msgSubject to "qwerty"

tell application "Mail"

    # Create the message *invisibly*, and assign subject text
    # as well as the HTML content.
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties ¬
        {visible:false, subject:msgSubject, html content:htmlContent}

    # Add recipients.
    # !! Given the workaround below, this is currently pointless.
    tell newMessage
        repeat with toRcpt in recipientList
            make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:toRcpt}
        end repeat
    end tell

    # Save the current number of drafts messages.
    set draftCountBefore to count messages of drafts mailbox

    # !! Save the new message as a *draft* - this is necessary
    # for the HTML content to actually appear in the message
    # body when we open the message interactively later.
    save newMessage

    # !! Sadly, it takes a little while for the new message
    # !! to appear in the drafts mailbox, so we must WAIT.
    set newMessageAsDraft to missing value
    repeat with i from 1 to 30 # give up after n * 0.1 secs.
        set draftCountNow to (count messages of drafts mailbox)
        if draftCountNow > draftCountBefore then
            set newMessageAsDraft to message 1 of drafts mailbox
            exit repeat
        end if
        delay 0.1 # sleep a little
    end repeat

    # Abort, if the draft never appeared.
    if newMessageAsDraft is missing value then error "New message failed to appear in the drafts mailbox within the timeout period."

    # Open the new message as a *draft* message - this ensures that 
    # the HTML content is displayed and editable in the message body.
    # !! The ONLY solution I found is to use `redirect`, which, unfortunately,
    # !! *wipes out the recipients*.
    # !! It does, however, ensure that the draft is deleted once the message is sent.
    redirect newMessageAsDraft with opening window

    # Activate Mail.app and thus the draft message's window.
    activate

    # !! Since the recipients have been wiped out, we need to
    # !! add them again - unfortunately, the only way we can do that is to
    # !! *GUI scripting* - simulating invocation of a menu command or
    # !! sending keystrokes.
    tell application "System Events"

        # We must make sure that the target window is active before
        # we can perform GUI scripting on it.
        set newMessageWindow to missing value
        repeat with i from 1 to 30 # give up after n * 0.1 secs.
            tell (first window of (first process whose frontmost is true) whose subrole is not "AXFloatingWindow")
                if name is msgSubject then
                    set newMessageWindow to it
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end tell
            delay 0.1 # sleep a little
        end repeat
        if newMessageWindow is missing value then error "New message failed to become the active window within the timeout period."

        # Turn the list of recipients into comma-delimited *string* for pasting into the To field.
        set {orgTIDs, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, {","}}
        set recipientListString to (recipientList as text)
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to orgTIDs

        # Save the current clipboard content.
        set prevClipboardContents to the clipboard

        # Cursor is in the  "To:" field, so use GUI scripting to send the Edit > Paste command now.
        # NOTE: Access for assistive devices must be enabled via System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Accessibility.
        set the clipboard to recipientListString
        my pasteFromClipboard("")

        # Restore the previous clipboard content.
        # !! We mustn't do this instantly, as our temporary content may not have
        # !! finished pasting yet. It would be non-trivial to determine
        # !! when pasting has finished (examining `count of to recipients` doesn't work), 
        # !! so we take our chances with a fixed, small delay.
        delay 0.1
        set the clipboard to prevClipboardContents

        # Place the cursor in the message *body*.
        # !! This works as of Mail.app on OS X 10.9.2, but may break in the future.
        try
            tell newMessageWindow
                tell UI element 1 of scroll area 1
                    set value of attribute "AXFocused" to true
                end tell
            end tell
        end try

    end tell

end tell

(*
 Pastes form the clipboard into the active window of the specified application (process) using GUI scripting
 rather than keyboard shortcuts so as to avoid conflicts with keyboard shortcuts used to invoke this handler.
 Specify "" or `missing value` to paste into the currently active (frontmost) application.
 The target process may be specified by either name or as a process object.

 CAVEAT: While this subroutine IS portable across *UI languages*, it does make an assumption that will hopefully hold for 
 all applications: that the "Edit" menu is the *4th* menu from the left (Apple menu, app menu, File, Edit).

 Examples:
     my pasteFromClipboard("") # paste into frontmost app
     my pasteFromClipboard("TextEdit")
*)
on pasteFromClipboard(targetProcess)
    tell application "System Events"
        if targetProcess is missing value or targetProcess = "" then
            set targetProcess to first process whose frontmost is true
        else
            if class of targetProcess is text then
                set targetProcess to process targetProcess
            end if
            -- Activate the application (make it frontmost), otherwise pasting will not work.
            set frontmost of targetProcess to true
        end if
        tell menu 1 of menu bar item 4 of menu bar 1 of targetProcess
            -- Find the menu item whose keyboard shortcut is Cmd-V
            set miPaste to first menu item whose value of attribute "AXMenuItemCmdChar" is "V" and value of attribute "AXMenuItemCmdModifiers" is 0
            click miPaste
        end tell
    end tell
end pasteFromClipboard
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what your are looking for, but I'll do my best to offer some help.

If you leave `send` commented, then the message should already be open in Mail.app, waiting for further editing and sending.

By adding the line `save newMessage`, it will be saved to the drafts folder. The user can open it and continue editing whenever they please. If you want to actually send the draft from your application, use:

```
set sendMessage to first message of drafts mailbox
send sendMessage
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see that you needed to edit the message before sending, so my previous answer was wrong. This time it should be correct.

It basically

- takes a preformatted RTF file,
- renders it & puts it into the clipboard,
- creates a new message,
- fills in the fields,
- moves the focus to the message body,
- pastes the formatted clipboard

Here is the code:

```
set textSubject to "HTML Test"
set toAddress to "john.doe@gmail.com"
set toName to "John Doe"

tell application "Mail"
    do shell script "cat ~/Documents/RTF\\ File.rtf | textutil -stdin -stdout -convert rtf | pbcopy"

    set refMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {name:toName, address:toAddress, subject:textSubject, visible:true}
    tell refMessage
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:toName, address:toAddress}
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Mail"
        set frontmost to true
        set value of attribute "AXFocused" of scroll area 4 of window textSubject to true
    end tell
    keystroke "v" using {command down}
end tell
```

Again, this worked fine on Snow Leopard

Hope that helped.

Comment: Normally [Link only responses](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65277/are-link-only-answers-poor-practice) are frowned upon.

Comment: Ack. Thx for heads up.

Comment: getting an error cannot set outgoing message on your code.. can you please confirm ?

Comment: Compiles and runs fine for me. I did find that the scroll area needed to be 4, I don't know why I had 3 originally but I changed it now. FYI this is Mail app v4.6 on 10.6.8

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML file's contents is a real HTML, then following script will create in Mail.app outgoing message with its contents. No GUI scripting involved. After sending to yourself you can confirm that the links and other rich content is preserved.

```
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "AppKit"
use scripting additions

-- classes, constants, and enums used
property NSUTF8StringEncoding : a reference to 4
property NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail : a reference to current application's NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail
property NSAttributedString : a reference to current application's NSAttributedString
property NSString : a reference to current application's NSString
property NSSharingService : a reference to current application's NSSharingService

set messageSubject to "Sending the message with html file contents."
set recipientAddresses to {"kniazidis.rompert@gmail.com"} -- I will send to myself, to test

set htmlContent to read (POSIX path of (choose file))

set theSource to NSString's stringWithString:htmlContent
set theData to theSource's dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
set anAttributedString to NSAttributedString's alloc()'s initWithHTML:theData documentAttributes:{}

-- USE THE MAIL SHARING SERVICE TO CREATE A NEW MAIL MESSAGE
set aSharingService to NSSharingService's sharingServiceNamed:(NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail)
if aSharingService's canPerformWithItems:recipientAddresses then
    set aSharingService's subject to messageSubject
    set aSharingService's recipients to recipientAddresses
    tell aSharingService to performSelectorOnMainThread:"performWithItems:" withObject:{anAttributedString} waitUntilDone:false
end if
```